# How to change the scope of existing VM in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, neural-network, google-compute-engine, tpu

I created a windows VM where I have the BERT master, SQUAD, and BERT-large model. I tried to run the squad using this:

```
python run_squad.py \
  --vocab_file=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/vocab.txt \
  --bert_config_file=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/bert_config.json \
  --init_checkpoint=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/bert_model.ckpt \
  --do_train=True \
  --train_file=$SQUAD_DIR/train-v2.0.json \
  --do_predict=True \
  --predict_file=$SQUAD_DIR/dev-v2.0.json \
  --train_batch_size=24 \
  --learning_rate=3e-5 \
  --num_train_epochs=2.0 \
  --max_seq_length=384 \
  --doc_stride=128 \
  --output_dir=gs://some_bucket/squad_large/ \
  --use_tpu=True \
  --tpu_name=$TPU_NAME \
  --version_2_with_negative=True
```

It threw an error: `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://tpu.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/projects/projectname/locations/us-central1-a/nodes/testnode?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">`

Is there a way to change the scope of existing VM to `cloud-platform` after VM is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the scope of existing VM to cloud-platform
>   after VM is created?

Yes you can. Go to the Google Cloud Console. Select your instance and stop it. Then edit your instance and change the scopes, etc. The restart your instance.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the scope of Compute Engine to read/write, however, I am unable to resolve the issue of Authentication problem in the VM even after the scope change. Am I looking at the error in the wrong side?

Comment: @JeevaBharathi Look at the service account assigned to the VM. Then review the roles assigned to that service account.